# How Can I use the GtkPlug/GtkSocket in GTK+

Tags: c, ubuntu, gtk

I'm a newbie to GTK+, I want to use GtkPlug/GtkSocket to embed another application with my application. I referred to Devhelp, but only a few introduction about these two class. I also  searched many days, but I failed to find a demo.
Can somebody show me how to use GtkPlug/GtkSocket? complete source code and explanation is better. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be a section in the GTKmm tutorial, here is the content that is no longer present: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm-documentation/-/commit/2c11fad94458d4e72998e13aa1de8d7f742ce74b

Even though it is in C++, it gives a good example of how to write a simple plug-socket system. However, since I originally wrote this answer 10 years ago, the best practice has changed to "don't do this".